# PHP function to loop SQL result and generate HTML tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to write an php function that will echo sql query results in a specific manner.

Example I have `table 1` which is `10.000 rows` * `43 columns`:

`NO NAME Prof Date of birth
1 John Teacher 1987
2 Nick Engineer 1976
3
4
5`

And so on. Based on `No` which is an `integer` (1-10.000), I want to generate tables such as:

`Name: John
Prof: Teacher
Date of birth: 1987`

`Name: Nick
Prof: Engineer
Date of birth: 1976`

So far my code:

`

```
    $hostname = "";     
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "db1";

    //connection to the database
    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname)
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
    /*echo "Connected to db1 database <br>";
    else
    echo "Could not connect"; */

    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `table 1` WHERE CODE_NO = 1";
    $query2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM table 1";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);

    // Check result
    // Useful for debugging.
     if (!$result1) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query1;
        die($message);
    }

    echo "<table>"; // table tag in the HTML
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
        //Creates a loop to loop through results
        {
        echo

        "<tr>
            <th>CODE_NO:</th>
            <td>" . $row['CODE_NO'] . "</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>FIRST_NAME:</th>
            <td>" . $row['FIRST_NAME'] . "</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>SURNAME:</th>
            <td>" . $row['SURNAME'] . "</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Date of birth:</th>
            <td>" . $row['DOB'] . "</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Date of death:</th>
            <td> " . $row['DOD'] . "</td>
        </tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

    ?>`
```

Is it possbile to code the process once, without hard-coding anything, so it could be repeated as many times as needed?

Edit:

`$x = 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM`persons`WHERE CODE_NO = '$x'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);`

Comment: *"Is it possbile to code the process once, without hard-coding anything, so it could be repeated as many times as needed?"* ... what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Yes. Do as you described what to do. Put the rows in an array, loop through the row-array and through the columns-array.

Comment: @CD001 These last lines might not be needed, as it seems they are rather confusing. You can edit them out if you like, since the problem is clearly described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this would do what you need:

```
function generateTableFromResult($result) {
   $html = "<table>";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      foreach($row as $column => $value) {
        $html.="<tr><th>".$column."</th><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
      }
   }
   $html.="</table>";
   return $html;
}

// usage:
// ...
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
echo generateTableFromResult($result1);
```

Comment: I am getting `syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)`. If I remove it though your code seems to work fine.

Comment: `0 1
CODE_NO 1
1 ΑΒΑΡΙΚΙΩΤΗΣ μΚΩΣΤΟΠΟΥΛΟΣ
SURNAME ΑΒΑΡΙΚΙΩΤΗΣ μΚΩΣΤΟΠΟΥΛΟΣ` is what your loop returns. Make it vertically

Comment: well, if you don't want a row for each column (as you had in your example!) put the `<tr>` and `</tr>` outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the excepted result.
You will need to have a variable to be incremented with the values and returned at the end.

See my example:

```
// Check result
// Useful for debugging.
 if (!$result1) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query1;
    die($message);
}

$table = "<table>"; // table tag in the HTML
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    //Creates a loop to loop through results
    $table .="<tr>";
    $table .="  <th>CODE_NO:</th>";
    $table .="  <td>" . $row['CODE_NO'] . "</td>";
    $table .="</tr>";
    $table .="<tr>";
    $table .="    <th>FIRST_NAME:</th>";
    $table .="    <td>" . $row['FIRST_NAME'] . "</td>";
    $table .="</tr>";
    $table .="<tr>";
    $table .="    <th>SURNAME:</th>";
    $table .="    <td>" . $row['SURNAME'] . "</td>";
    $table .="</tr>";
    $table .="<tr>";
    $table .="   <th>Date of birth:</th>";
    $table .="   <td>" . $row['DOB'] . "</td>";
    $table .="</tr>";
    $table .="<tr>";
    $table .="    <th>Date of death:</th>";
    $table .="    <td> " . $row['DOD'] . "</td>";
    $table .="</tr>";
    }
$table .= "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
echo $table;
?>`
```

This is a possible approach to get the result that you want. 
However you sent an array in the json format with the values and in the front end build the table using js.

Comment: I am not familiar with `js`, thank you for the answer though.

Comment: I also tried your code and even though I am not getting an error nothing shows in html.

Comment: _"nothing shows in html"_ - because of this `$table = "</table>";` at the very end. should be `$table .= "</table>";`

Comment: Yes. I have a misstake should be $table.="</table>"; insted of $table ="</table>";

Comment: You don't provide the increment bit. I 've added a variable `$x = 1;` where should I put the `$x = $x +1;` part in order to work?

Comment: You shold use $x++ to increment the variable.

I need to use our code to analyse where you are using the $x variable

Comment: I am using `$x=1;` before the sql query. Then inside the query `WHERE No = 'x'"` and Inside the loop before ending `}` I place `$x++; `. See edit on post.

Answer (score 0):

Revised function generateTableFromResult from above that works correctly

```
function generateTableFromResult($result) {
   $html = "";
   $i = 0;
   $header = "<tr>";
   $body = "";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $i += 1;
      
      $body .= "<tr>\n";
      foreach($row as $column => $value) {
          if ($i == 1){
              $header .= "<th>$column</th>\n";
          }
         $body .= "<td>$value</td>\n";
      }
      $body .= "</tr>\n";
   }
   $header .= "</tr>\n";
   $html .= "<table> $header $body</table>";
   return $html;
}
```